# I'm despairing of using Interop.Excel in Visual Studio 2022 - the library can't be loaded

Tags: excel, office-interop

I've tried everything - I swear...
But now I am running out of ideas and need some expert help.

I've already been using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in the past.
But now, something seems to have changed.

Whatever I am trying, I can't get rid of that dll-error:

---

System.InvalidCastException:
'Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass'
to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'.
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the
interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error:
Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).'

---

**MY ENVIRONMENT:**
**My VS version:**
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.4.4

**Interop.Excel version and path:**
Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll

**Office:**
I am using Office 365.

**1. started from scratch**
To exclude everything else, I've set up a completely new project with nothing in there apart from the using-directive. And... I get the same error (see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZHFN.png).

**2. added reference in different ways**
I've added the reference from the COM list, but also tried to directly use the path - no difference.

**checked the file location and version**
The file is exactly where it should be.
I can't see any newer version of the DLL for download either.

**updated to the latest .NET version**
Nothing changed.

Do you have an idea how I could solve this error?
(Please be gracious with your answer - I had a few years programming break and am just starting up again...)

Have a good day!
Katrin

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an off-the-shelf solution for this, but any problem in VS 2022 related to COM interop reeks of 32/64-bit issues. Here are some thoughts:

Are you using 32-bit office? Check: File => Account => About Excel, and see what it says in bold font at the top.
Are you building for AnyCpu, or are you targeting a specific architecture (x86/x64)?
You could also check the registry to see if your assembly is actually registered for the correct "bitness", i.e. the one matching Excel.
VS2022 defaults to 64-bit if you're building AnyCpu, as opposed to earlier (32-bit) versions of VS.

/Einar

Comment: Thank you for your reply and hints, Einar!

I am using O365 and my Excel version is Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2301 Build 16.0.16026.20002) 64-bit. Else, I did not make any special settings in VS, just created a new forms project.

However, I meanwhile gave up and used the NuGet package "ClosedXML", which works fine. Although I'd still be interested to know why the Interop.Excel doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I switched to the NuGet package "ClosedXML", which works fine. This should work for others with the same problem too.

Hint: Before installing, check the hints on the ClosedXml Website. The installation doesn't work the usual way (FEB-23), but there's an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Install the nugget package 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' and just put the using at the top, and there was no error.